# Theorem or just a change of varibles?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I have a formula in my text:

> $$\int \int_{S} F \cdot n dA= \int \int_{w} F(G(u,v)) \cdot (dG_{u}\times dG_{v}) du dv$$

I am really lazy and hate remembering formulas  to me this looks like a change of variables from x,y to u,v with a new normal vector to this surface can someone derive this? id much rather just remember the derivation that and if im write this should apply to higher dimensions i just need to know how to apply it.

**Edit:** the only reason i can't do a normal change of variables  is the n the formula makes u sub in the values of n from the change of varibles then cross product them out and im not sure why, i can blindly follow the formula but well this isnt physics id rather just know how to do it.

Comment: Please have a look dear Faust7 if I made it better correctly in looking. :)

Comment: m8 i don't think you could of made it worse and it had the same meaning no matter how hard u tried =) ty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the definition of a surface integral. If you were integrating over two different regions in the plane, it would be a change of variables. But you're not far off: The unit normal is
$$n =\frac{\frac{\partial G}{\partial u}\times\frac{\partial G}{\partial v}}{\|{\frac{\partial G}{\partial u}\times\frac{\partial G}{\partial v}}\|}\,,$$
and you can think of the element of surface area on the surface as
$$dA = \Big\|{\frac{\partial G}{\partial u}\times\frac{\partial G}{\partial v}}\Big\|\,du\,dv\,.$$
To see this, remember that the magnitude of the cross-product of two vectors is the area of the parallelogram they span, and a little bit of surface is approximated by the tangential parallelogram with sides $\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial u}\Delta u$ and $\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial v}\Delta v$.